# Version Control in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, release-management

If you have 1 folder for Dev in VSS and then you create another folder for PrePROD in VSS and copy all latest versions from Dev folder in to PrePROD folder then what will be the version number of all the files in PREPROD folder? Will it be version 1?

Thanks,

Priyesh T